# Adding time differences to a series of files

Tags: r, if-statement, lubridate

I am trying to create a function where I batch process a folder of CSV files. All of the CSV files contain timestamps that are incorrect so I have another file with the difference between the timestamp that is incorrect and the corresponding correct timestamp. For example, my files look like this:

```
df1
ID        Visit    Difference (in seconds)
1002      V2       35
2038      V1       86786

df2
ID        Visit    startTime
1002      V2       2017-12-01 19:47:11
1002      V2       2017-12-01 19:49:55
1002      V2       2017-12-01 19:50:42
1002      V2       2017-12-01 20:18:24

...
```

I tried to create an if statement to add the difference if the ID and visit number matched

```
if (df1$ID == df2$ID &
      df1$Visit == df2$Visit) {
    df2$startTime <- df2$startTime + df1$Difference
  }
```

It repeats adding the 35 seconds then 86786 seconds then 35 etc. so I get an output like this

```
ID        Visit    startTime
1002      V2       2017-12-01 19:47:46
1002      V2       2017-12-02 19:56:21
1002      V2       2017-12-01 19:51:17
1002      V2       2017-12-02 20:24:50
```

I want it to only add the 35 seconds. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can help:

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
# reproduce similar data
df1 <-
  data.frame(
    "ID" = c(1002, 2038),
    "Visit" = as.character(c("V2", "V1")),
    "Difference" = c(35, 86786)
  )
df2 <-
  data.frame(
    "ID" = c(rep(1002, 3), 2038),
    Visit = as.character(rep("V2", 4)),
    startTime = ymd_hms(
      "2017-12-01 19:47:11",
      "2017-12-01 19:49:55",
      "2017-12-01 19:50:42",
      "2017-12-01 20:18:24"
    )
  )
# join before adding time
df <- left_join(df2, df1, by = c("ID", "Visit"))
df %>%
  mutate(new_time = if_else(!is.na(Difference),
                            startTime + Difference,
                            startTime))
```